# What is meant by Protocols & Scripting Language in HP Load Runner? How can I choose these?

Tags: loadrunner

In our company, we have two applications one is developed in Dot Net & MSSQL (DB) and another one is on JAVA & DB2 (DB).
Both are webbased applications.

1. What kind of protocols I have to select in HP Load Runner.  Just Web(HTTP/HTML) ??
2. What language I have to use. Just C language or can I use VB Scripting.
3. How can I identify what kind of protocols need to be selected before recording a script in HP Load Runner.

Thanks in advance for all your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Foundation skills are required for performance testing independent of the tool selected.  In this case you should be investigating the client architecture along with what communications protocols (OSI Layers 6 & 7 Generally) that are used to communicate from the client to the next upstream architectural component.  As you will be reproducing the client behavior (regardless of whether you have a mainframe, mini, midrange, big honking unix or windows box three to ten tiers back) it is this client side piece you need to concentrate on.

You read like someone who has simply been tossed into this role.  If this is true, you need training.  You also will need a mentor for a period of time.  The amount of skills you will need which are tool related are somewhere between 5-15% of the total skills you will need in a performance testing role.  I have already noted the skill of client architecture above, but their are many many others that you will have to be a master of, or be in a team which has mastered of which you are an intern.

Have your boss send you to training (absolute minimum).  Or else just expect they are setting you up to fail.  And when it fails you will become the person with the blame.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing some proper performance test planning before you consider protocols. You need to come up with what the performance test scenario will look like. Momentarily ignore the technology used and examine how the software is actually *used*. If users access the system through a web interface then the protocol you need is web. If there are interfaces which apply background load which needs to be simulated then you may need a non-web protocol.

In Loadrunner you will pretty much only use C, there is a .NET protocol but it's highly unlikely you will be using this even though your application under test is .NET. This protocol is more for .NET rich client applications.

Loadrunner also comes with a protocol advisor to help you.